# Frama-C Error with unbound logic variable?

Tags: c, frama-c

I'm trying to generate a proof for a function that allocates to a void pointer, but when I write `\valid(a)` Frama-C can't process it because it's an unbound logic variable

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/*@
  requires \valid(a);
*/
static inline void xmalloc(const unsigned int sz) {
  void *a = malloc(sz);
}
```

With error

```
[kernel] Parsing test.c (with preprocessing)
[kernel:annot-error] test.c:4: Warning: 
  unbound logic variable a. Ignoring logic specification of function xmalloc
[kernel] User Error: warning annot-error treated as fatal error.
[kernel] User Error: stopping on file "test.c" that has errors. Add '-kernel-msg-key pp'
  for preprocessing command.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

Based on Alan Blanchard's tutorial I expected this to work just fine, but apparently I'm missing something.

EDIT:

I fixed the unbound logic variable, now it is having trouble because I can't use a pointer to void?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/*@
  requires sz >= 1;
  assigns \nothing;
  ensures \valid(\result);
*/
void *xmalloc(const unsigned int sz) {
  void *a = malloc(sz);
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Your *function* **leaks** `a`.

Comment: Ah so the error is because `a` is allocated but not returned anywhere? When I change it to return `a` it still complains about the unbound variable.

Comment: No, the error is because `a` is a local variable of the `xmalloc`, hence not in scope for the contract. An ACSL function contract can only speak about global variables and the formals of the function. Moreover, I fail to see what you'd like to express here. Remember that a `requires` is a constraint over the _callers_ of `xmalloc`. How could they provide a valid pointer if the call to malloc is done within `xmalloc`? Didn't you mean to write an `ensures` (something `xmalloc` guarantees upon `return`?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I've updated the question with the new bug that appears.

Comment: If you are writing a simple allocation function, I'd recommend reading the [ACSL reference](https://www.frama-c.com/download/acsl.pdf), specifically the section about *Dynamic allocation and deallocation*. There is an example specification for function `malloc` there.